# Sorting smartpointer of custom classes with std::sort

Tags: c++, sorting, smart-pointers

The issue I have is that I have a vector of `shared_ptr` of a custom class which implements `operator<`.

When using the class on the stack I can use std::sort without specifying `Compare` as sort parameter. But of course when I use `shared_ptr` it (obviously I think) tries to sort the pointers and not the object themselves.

I was wondering if it's possible to call the `std::sort` on a container with smart pointers and make it possible to still call the Compare operator of the actual objects and not the pointers **without** providing the 3rd argument to ‘sort’.

For completeness a MWE:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

class Date
{
public:
    Date(int y, int m) : year(y), month(m) {}
    bool operator<(const Date& rhs)
    {
        if (year > rhs.year) return false;
        else if (year == rhs.year)
        {
            return month < rhs.month;
        }
        return true;
    }
    int year;
    int month;
};

int main()
{
    Date d1(1999,12);
    Date d3(2000,10);
    Date d2(2000,1);
    Date d4(1997,9);

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Date>> dates = {std::make_shared<Date>(d1), std::make_shared<Date>(d2), std::make_shared<Date>(d3), std::make_shared<Date>(d4)};

    std::sort(dates.begin(), dates.end()); // doesn't work. orders by pointers

    // std::sort(dates.begin(), dates.end(), [](std::shared_ptr<Date> d1, std::shared_ptr<Date> d2) { return *d1 < *d2; }); // this works

    for (const auto& d : dates)
    {
        std::cout << d->year << " " << d->month << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Of course it's possible, and your commented-out `sort()` call is exactly how it's done (except to avoid useless copies the comparator should takes its parameters by reference).

Comment: Except you probably should pass `shared_ptr`s by const references to that lambda.

Comment: Is the *real* question you're asking whether it is possible to utilize some custom comparator *without* providing the third argument to `std::sort` ? Because you obviously already know how to provide a comparator argument.

Comment: @WhozCraig actually yes, that’s the question. I will rephrase

Comment: [OT]: Comparison might be simplified to `bool operator<(const Date& rhs) const {return std::tie(year, month) < std::tie(rhs.year, rhs.month); }`.

Comment: You need extra layer to avoid to explicitly use the 3rd parameter: `my_sort` which adds it for you, or wrapping `shared_ptr` in something which compare value and not pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you figured out, the compare operator of `std::shared_ptr` uses the pointer it refers to. This way 2 allocated instances that compare equal still compare as unequal.

Explicitly sorting with a function is a good thing.

```
std::sort(dates.begin(), dates.end(), [](std::shared_ptr<Date> d1, std::shared_ptr<Date> d2) { return *d1 < *d2; });
```

However, if you have to do it at several places, you could wrap the ptr in a class/struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct SharedPtr final
 {
       std::shared_ptr<T> ptr;
       bool operator==(const T &rhs) const
        { return *ptr == rhs; }
       bool operator==(const SharedPtr<T> &rhs) const
        { return *ptr == *rhs.ptr; }
      // ...
 };
```

Feel free to extend with nullptr checks, other overloads and operator<

Answer (score 1):

In your case, providing 3rd parameter is required. However if you are going to use this a lot you can simplify it by creating a special struct which overloads `operator()`

```
class Date
{
public:
    struct CompareSharedPtr
    {
        bool operator()(const std::shared_ptr<Date>& d1, const std::shared_ptr<Date>& d2)
        {
            return *d1 < *d2;
        }
    };
    Date(int y, int m) : year(y), month(m) {}
    bool operator<(const Date& rhs)
    {
        if (year > rhs.year) return false;
        else if (year == rhs.year)
        {
            return month < rhs.month;
        }
        return true;
    }
    int year;
    int month;
};
```

and usage

```
std::sort(dates.begin(), dates.end(), Date::CompareSharedPtr{});
```